# IO ERROR(ERRNO 20) while Accessing a file inside a folder in python

Tags: python, file, errno, ioerror

***This is a code for accessing a file inside a folder using with open() as:{} option.***

```
with open("DATABASE\password.txt") as _2_:
    password=_2_.readlines()
with open("DATABASE/names.txt") as _3_:
    names=_3_.readlines()
with open("DATABASE\email.txt") as _4_:
    email=_4_.readlines()
```

In this code, if I put "DATABASE\names.txt", as I did for password and email; instead of "DATABASE/names.txt"; it does not work. Please Tell me the reason for the same.

Comment: If you indent your code 4 spaces it will appear as a code block distinct from normal text. Its hard to read the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the \, use raw string r or forward slashes as you have already tried:

```
"DATABASE\\names.txt" # double \
r"DATABASE\names.txt" # raw string
"DATABASE/names.txt" # use forward slashes
```

`\n` is a newline character.

```
In [7]: print "DATABASE\names.txt" # interpreted as two lines
DATABASE
ames.txt

In [8]: print r"DATABASE\names.txt"
DATABASE\names.txt
```

A backslash has a special meaning in python, it is used to [escape](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) characters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another backslash. Example: `open("path\\to\\file.txt")`

Your errors are happening because you need to escape the backslash by adding another one. Such a thing won't happen with `/`.